# How to cancel a sort?

Tags: sortablejs

I'm not understanding how to cancel a sort.  If I drag outside the target area or hit the escape key while dragging, there is an animation that has the draggable return to original position.  But the resulting HTML order is still the new order, and not the order before the drag started.  I can't see the way to undo the sort after the drag starts, after some onMove events happen, when the drag ends.  Please advise.